# How can I add a field to each row of an array with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript variable:

```
var x = 
{"ab":"x",
 "cd":"y",
 "de":"z",
 "answers":[
    {"answerId":222,"answerUId":1,"text":"x"},
    {"answerId":223,"answerUId":2,"text":"A"},
    {"answerId":224,"answerUId":3,"text":"A"}
 ]
}
```

How can I add a field to each element of the answers array called response with a value of null ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add the new property to the objects, like this

```
x["answers"].forEach(function(currentObject) {
    currentObject["response"] = null;
});
```

This iterates through each and every object and adds the `response` property to each of them.

Comment: forEach is native javascript

Comment: @Otanaught It just requires a browser that supports ECMAScript 5.1: [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Oh i see, just checked the [MDN about forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Watch out for browser backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

Plain javascript:

```
for (key in x['answers']) {
    x['answers'][key]['response'] = null;
}
```

Comment: Iterating an array with `for..in` is bad.

Comment: @thefourtheye could you please explain why?

Comment: Just check the boxed items in [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description)

Comment: @thefourtheye - The caution in the boxed items recommends against using `for..in` only _"where index order is important"_. I don't see that index order is important here.